Compute $F^*\omega$ on a smooth manifold

Let $F:M\to N$  be a map, and M and N be smooth manifolds.  Consider
$M=N=\mathbb{R}^2$; $
F(s,t)=(st,e^t);$
$\omega=x\text{d}y-y\text{d}x$.

Compute $F^*\omega$.
Let us use the form:
$F^*\omega=F^*(dy)=d(F^*y)=d(y\circ F)$
and
$F^*\omega=F^*(dx)=d(F^*x)=d(x\circ F)$
But how do we move from here, considering the s and t variable? I thought that one needs to calculate the Jacobian that gives
$$dF=\begin{pmatrix} t & s \\ 0 & e^t\end{pmatrix}$$
The determinant is $$\det dF=te^t$$
Then I check that $\omega$ is closed: $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial y}=1$$ . It is closed.
Now we   integrate the first component:
$$\int x dy= xy+C(x)$$
Using:
$$y=\frac{\partial }{\partial }\bigg(xy+C(x)\bigg)\implies C(x)=0$$
That gives that $$f=xy$$.
From here  I am not sure what to do.
Any ideas appreciated!
Thanks

See Calculating simple pullbacks. But really, you should know by now that this is not a good question; you haven’t shown any effort.

@peek-a-boo see my update

$\omega$ is not closed.

@KurtG. how can it be open when the partial derivatives are equal?

$d\omega=dx\wedge dy-dy\wedge dx=2,dx\wedge dy,.$

I dont get it, I have an example in Lee where $\omega=y\cos{xy}dx+x\cos{xy}dy$, where he solves the $$\frac{\partial (y\cos{xy})}{\partial y}$$ and $$\frac{\partial (x\cos{xy})}{\partial x}$$ and obtains that they are equal, hence it is closed.

In  $\omega=x,dy\color{red}-y,dx$ the sign in front of $y$ matters. The $f(x,y)=xy$ you derived has $df=x,dy\color{red}+y,dx,.$

@KurtG.  thanks for that.

@KurtG. so when found $f(x,y)=xy$ , how is that used to obtain $F^*\omega$?

You don't need that $f(x,y)=xy,.$ Pullbacks exist for all forms. Not only for the closed ones.

I feel like you haven’t read my linked answer. It goes through essentially this and a more difficult question.

We have
\begin{align}
\omega&=x\,dy-y\,dx\,,&F(s,t)&=(ts,e^t)\,,&dF=\pmatrix{t&s\\0&e^t}\pmatrix{ds\\dt}\,.
\end{align}
The differential we can also write as
\begin{align}
dF_1&=dx=t\,ds+s\,dt\,,&dF_2&=dy=e^t\,dt\,.
\end{align}
Putting the expressions for $dx,dy$ into $\omega$ yields
\begin{align}
F^*\omega&=\underbrace{ts}_{x}\,\underbrace{e^t\,dt}_{dy}-\underbrace{e^t}_y\,\underbrace{(t\,ds+s\,dt)}_{dx}=s(t-1)\,e^t\,dt-te^t\,ds\,.\tag1
\end{align}
This is the simplest way to do the pullback.
In a more orthodox fashion:
\begin{align}
F^*(dx)&=d(F^*x)=d(ts)=t\,ds+s\,dt\,,&F^*(dy)&=d(F^*y)=d(e^t)=e^t\,dt\,,&\\[2mm]
\end{align}
which leads of course to the same pullback (1).

Thanks, I see how this comes around then. Thanks
