Calculating a pullback function where the map has an extra dimension compared to the covector field
I have the given manifold map: $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$, where
$$F(\theta,\phi)=\bigg( (\cos\phi+2)\cos\theta, (\cos\phi+2)\sin\theta, \sin\phi\bigg) $$
and the covector field $$\omega=z^2\text{d}x$$
When I need to solve the Jacobian, it is tricky because it has three functions but only two variables. That gives at best the following:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} ((\cos\phi+2)\cos\theta) & \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} ((\cos\phi+2)\cos\theta)\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}((\cos\phi+2)\sin\theta) & \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}((\cos\phi+2)\sin\theta)\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\sin\phi & \frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}\sin\phi
\end{pmatrix}$$
However, it is not clear to me how can I solve for the Determinant of this Jacobian, since we have no third variable. Any hints appreciated.
Thanks

I'm confused, why are you talking about the Jacobian? What exactly do you want to do?

You can see this  post to see why I need to compute the Jacobian: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4918030/compute-f-omega-on-a-smooth-manifold?noredirect=1#comment10503365_4918030

We don't need the Jacobian. To pull back $z^2,dx,,$ what is $z^2$ and what is $dx$ in the $(\phi,\theta)$-coordinates?

@KurtG. $$z^2=\rho^2 cos^2\phi$$.  $$dx=dF_1=((\cos\phi+2)\cos\theta)^2)$$ if I am not mistaking

Your question should be self-contained.

You mistook for $z$ its representation in spherical polar coordinates. Totally wrong. You need the $z$-component of $F,:$ $z=\sin\phi,.$ What is $x,?$ (Hint: follow same logic.) I can, for the life of me, not find a reason for your $dx,.$

@KurtG. thanks for confirming the error. $x=(\cos\phi+2)\cos\theta$

Then what is $dx?$ Easy isn't it?

Yes, we get what Alex wrote, $\text{d}\big((\cos\phi+2)\cos\theta\big)$. Now I will try another more challenging one.  The only thing I didn't get is why you  set $F:z=\sin\phi$. Is this ubiquitous for all pullbacks?

I did not set $F:z=\sin\phi.$ That was the person giving you that homework. Good luck with more challenging examples.

@KurtG. where did you find that?It is not in the OP, nor is it  in my homework. All I know about F is that it $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$. Thanks

@MoisheKohan what do you mean?

You wrote (and therefore should know that) $$F(\theta,\phi)=\bigg( (\cos\phi+2)\cos\theta, (\cos\phi+2)\sin\theta, \sin\phi\bigg),.$$ What is the $z$--component of this $F,?$

Ok, I think I get it, you focus on the $z$ component because you look at what the covector field contains, $\omega=z^2$? If it contained $y^2$, you would look at the y-component of $F$...

What is frustrating is that you sometimes seem to be on the right track and then write nonsense such as $\omega=z^2,.$ What was that $\omega$ again? The best thing now is probably if you stick to this $F$ invent another one-form $\omega$ and pull that back. These conversations have reached a dead end. We need to see you do it flawlessly yourself.

Clearly, $\omega=z^2dx$ that was just a typo of course.

To pullback, just substitute and compute the total derivative using the partial derivatives:
$$ F^*(z^2 dx) = (\sin \phi)^2 d((\cos\phi+2)\cos\theta) = -(\sin \phi)^2(\sin \phi\cos\theta d\phi + (\cos\phi+2)\sin\theta d\theta). $$

Thanks Alex, I am not sure how you got that first term in the middle, but I will look at it closer.
